# How do I provide TSC with typescript definitions for URI imports?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

```
import Vue from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.esm.js'
```

If I ask TSC to compile the above it complains (reasonably so) about not being able to find definitions for that module.  However, I can not figure out how to give TypeScript the definition file.  `declare module 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.esm.js' { ... }` doesn't work, and `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.esm.js` isn't a valid filename so I can't create a file named that.  I tried using `tsconfig.json` `paths`, but couldn't get that to work either.

What is the magic required to get TypeScript to accept my Vue type definitions?

Note: An ideal solution would work with `//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.esm.js` and `./vue.esm.js` and `./vue.js` as well.  The latter two are relative paths which I can't figure out how to provide a definition path for.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is this:

**`stubs.d.ts`**

```
declare module 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.esm.js' {
  const Vue: typeof import ('vue');

  export default Vue;
}
```

However, using an import statement to load a module from a CDN is not an idiomatic way to use modules — and no bundler supports that, at least not to my knowledge.

If you want to use Vue as a module, it should be installed locally (`npm install vue`) and then imported from your local `node_modules` directory.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
```

If you want to use it as a UMD package (that is, make the browser download it from a CDN rather than from your bundle), then you need to install the typings and include them in your project.

Vue bundles its declaration files (`*.d.ts`) next to the actual executable code, so you cannot install just types. You need to download the entire package anyway.

```
npm install vue
```

Add the installed type definitions to your project. In your `tsconfig.json`, make sure `"vue"` is included in `compilerOptions.types`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vue"]
  }
}
```

This will expose the typings globally inside your scripts.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't address the problem, which is how do I make the ESM version of Vue work with the TypeScript compiler.  If you do `import Vue from 'https://...'` then tsc won't be able to match that with the `vue` type definition files.

Comment: The thing is you shouldn't be doing `import Vue from 'https://...'` — you should install Vue locally (`npm install vue`) and import it using the import statement, or use the CDN link in your HTML file.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how it could be done, but should not be done. ;-)

Comment: The question remains how to get type definitions associated with esm modules imported via https.