# Make TypeScript with JSDoc see reference libraries without import

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I am using TypeScript to type-check (without emitting) a JavaScript project. In the JavaScript project I am using JSDoc to make TypeScript's work easier, but I am also using 3rd party packages, which provide their own typings (not `@types`) and TypeScript doesn't see these packages, because they are referred to using only a simple `script` tag on the page.

I don't want to write typings for what the libraries contribute to `window` by hand since the packages already come with their own typings, TypeScript just doesn't see them and I wonder if there is a way to make it aware of them.

I cannot use `import` or `/// <reference`, because the source files are JavaScript files, not TypeScript files and I have to stick with what JavaScript allows.

I cannot use `@types` because the typings come from the packages directly, not `@types`. I might `npm install` the packages, but TypeScript has no way of knowing the project references them (no import etc.) so I assume there needs to be a compiler setting letting it know.

I have tried `npm install`ing the NPM packages of the dependencies TypeScript gets at runtime using `script` and setting up `typeRoots`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/package"
  ]
}
```

But this didn't have any effect.

I have also tried to configure "typeAcquisition" to do my bidding like this:

```
{
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true,
    "include": [
      "package"
    ]
  }
}
```

This didn't work either, which is understandable, because I think this just enables automatic fetching of `@types`, when in my case the typings are a part of the actual package like I said previously.

How can I make TypeScript aware my JavaScript project it typechecks references packages a way it can't see from the source so that it loads their typings and the global objects provided by the packages become recognized and type checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `compilerOptions.types`. It contains *type declaration files to be included in compilation*.

```
"types": [
  "package"
],
```

Comment: Is my understanding correct this will only pull @ types for the package and not index.d.ts nor typings field from package.json from the package itself? In my case the packages do not have @ types.

Comment: No — if your package has `typings` (or `types`) field in `package.json`, it will work. I described it in another case, where the package in question is Vue (which bundles its own types as well): https://stackoverflow.com/a/53794208/10325032.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it, but helped uncover another case I don't know how to deal with. Others may run into this as well: what if the typings are incorrectly presenting the dependency as if it was just a module file, but the actual code contributes to `window`? How can they be updated? The follow-up questions is https://stackoverflow.com/q/53958469/2715716