# How use type definitions for javascript modules imported via http link?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I import excalibur as a ESM module in my javascript project as follows:

```js
import { Engine, Actor } from 'https://esm.sh/excalibur'
```

I would like to have type checking so I installed ExcaliburJS using `npm init` and `npm install excalibur`, JUST to get the type definitions. I can see that the type definitions are in `node_modules/excalibur/build/esm/index.d.ts`. I specified this location in `jsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": false,
        "checkJs": true,
        "target": "ES2022",
        "lib": [
            "es2022",
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable"
        ],
        "module": "es2022",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "types": [
            "node_modules/excalibur/build/esm/index.d.ts"
        ]
    }
}
```

But I get the warning

```
Cannot find type definition file for 'node_modules/excalibur/build/esm/index.d.ts'. 
The file is in the program because: 
Entry point of type library 'node_modules/excalibur/build/esm/index.d.ts' specified in compilerOptions
```

This error goes away if I remove the `types` field, but type checking still doesn't work. My package.json looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "excaliquarium",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Pixel Aquarium",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "eerk",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "excalibur": "^0.27.0"
  }
}
```

How can I get type checking for modules imported with `import { Engine, Actor } from 'https://esm.sh/excalibur'` ?

BTW this question equally applies to other libraries such as ThreeJS and PIXI, which allow you to `import` esm modules directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I provide TSC with typescript definitions for URI imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792043/how-do-i-provide-tsc-with-typescript-definitions-for-uri-imports)

Comment: That answer just states that you shouldn’t import esm modules via https. I just want to know how you can force the IDE to use type definitions in case I do want to use ESM modules loaded via https